# How encoding correctly for mailing with smtplib in Python

Tags: python, email, character-encoding

I'm trying to make a python script to verify some file and send an email if there is some change.

The script is working good but if I wrote some special caracters, he won't send the mail...

I've looked website for encoding but I can not solve my problem.

Here is my script :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding:Latin-1 -*-

import os
import shutil
import smtplib

# Fonctions
def compare (old,new):
        x = 0
        if old == new:
                print('Les fichiers sont à jour')
                x = 0
        if old != new:
                print('Nouveaux Fichiers de tests')
                x = 1
                mail = open('mail.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8')
                mail.write("test d'écriture\n")
                mail.write("si ca marche c'est top\n")
                mail.close()
        return x

# Récupération des fichiers
os.chdir("/var/www/corealpi/integration/integration_core")
rep = os.getcwd()
print(rep)

# copie du fichier tests.txt
shutil.copyfile('tests.txt','/home/git/integration/tests.new')

os.chdir("/home/git/integration")
rep_int = os.getcwd()
print(rep_int)

# Ouverture des fichiers
oldFile = open('tests.old','r')
newFile = open('tests.new','r')
tOld = oldFile.read()
tNew = newFile.read()

verif = compare (tOld,tNew)
print(verif)
# Envoie de mails
if verif == 1:

        from email.mime.text import MIMEText
        mailfile = 'mail.txt'
        with open(mailfile) as fp:
                # Create a text/plain message
                msg = MIMEText(fp.read())
                msg.set_charset('utf-8')
        msg['Subject'] = 'Nouveaux Fichiers de %s' % mailfile
        msg['From'] = 'sender@mail.fr'
        msg['To'] = 'receiver@mail.fr'

        # Envoi du message
        s = smtplib.SMTP('192.168.3.2')
        s.send_message(msg)
        s.quit
else:
        print('Rien à signaler')
```

I encode in utf8... but it seems not work with `send_message` ? but perhaps I confused me or that I am too complicated life.

If someone can help me please ?

**EDIT :** I've tried to encoding in many way but I can't solve this problem... Please heeelp :)

Thanks for help.

Comment: Try `msg.set_charset('utf-8')`.

Comment: Thanks for help @MarkRansom. I've edit my script, but it seems no work. I've tried too something like that `msg = MIMEText(fp.read(), 'utf-8')` but it's the same...

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3 ? Or are you strings bytes or unicode ?

Comment: I use Python 3 sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to say what is the default encoding on your platform, and if you are using Python2 or 3.

I assume you use Python 2, but it should not be very different for Python 3.

In fact, you should set the charset in the `email.mime.text.MIMEText` object, because doc says that *charset defaults to us-ascii* which is wrong here. You should use :

```
msg = MIMEText(fp.read(), 'plain', charset)
```

where charset is the charset in which the data is encoded if you are using Python2, or the charset in which you want to encode the mail is you are using Python 3.

If you want to send the mail in UTF8 independently of the local encoding in Python 2, first decode it to an unicode string and then apply the output charset :

```
msg = MIMEText(fp.read().decode(charset), 'plain', 'utf-8')
```

Comment: Excuse-me, I use Python 3. So `msg = MIMEText(fp.read(), 'plain', charset)` solved my issue. But now when I receive my mail, I have this type of char : `Ã©cho`. So I think I have to re-encode after or something like that ?

Comment: @mestra No, it just means that your mail reader does not like utf-8 and displays it as latin1. Just set the charset to `latin1` and you should receive correctly your mail with  all accented chars. *Je connais également les problèmes d'accents :-)*

Comment: Ok... Yes I use Outlook... I will see that tomorrow. Thanks